# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' from attempt to create dict

Tags: python

I'm receiving the following error in my programm:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bookmarks.py", line 26, in <module>
    zipping = dict(zip(datelist, matchhref))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I want to make dictionary from two lists (`datelist` and `matchhref`), but somehow when I use `zip()`, it returns `list` instead of `tuple`.

Here's my code:

```
import re

bm_raw = open('bookmarks.txt', 'r')

bm_line = bm_raw.read()

matchhref = re.findall('(<DT><A HREF=".*?</A>)', bm_line)
massive = list()
datelist = list()
a = 0

for i in matchhref:

    temp = matchhref[a]
    found = re.findall('(\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d)', temp)
    datelist.append(found)
    a=a+1

print datelist
print matchhref
zipping = dict(zip(datelist, matchhref))
```

And here's contents of bookmarks.txt:

```
 <DT><A HREF="some random data" ADD_DATE="1460617925" ICON="some random data">priomap</A>
 <DT><A HREF="some random data" ADD_DATE="1455024833" ICON="some random data">V.34</A>
```

Comment: First off don't use regex to parse html, why your code fails is findall returns a list which you append to a list and then try to use as a key, if you want a single element use `re.search` and call `.group` and append that

Comment: Why not just `findall('\d{10}')` on each line of the file?

Comment: Obligatory - [Don't parse html/xml with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1547004)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented, you can call *re.search* and then *.group()* the add the *string* and not the *list* that *findall* returns so you can use the string as the key but [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) will make your life a lot easier:

```
In [50]:from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag

In [51]: soup = BeautifulSoup(h,"xml")

In [52]: print(dict((dt["ADD_DATE"], dt["HREF"],) for dt in soup.select("DT A[HREF]")))
{u'1455024833': u'some random data', u'1460617925': u'some random data'}
```

`select("DT A[HREF]")` finds all the *anchor tags* i.e `A` inside a *DT* tag that have a *HREF* attribute.

The regex solution would be:

```
    found = re.search('(\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d)', temp)     
    datelist.append(found.group())
```

But use a html parser like bs4 or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

`zip` returns a list of tuples, not a tuple.

Besides, a tuple is only hashable if each of its elements are hashable. So a tuple of lists will not be hashable either.

That said, there's nothing wrong with `dict(zip(keys, values))` if `keys` is a list of hashable elements. Your problem is that `datelist` contains lists (results of `re.findall`) which are not hashable and cannot be used as dict keys.

But really, read the advice given by others and don't use `re` to parse HTML. BeautifulSoup is my preferred tool.